# How to make the compiler throw a warning on functions whose types are not explicitly specified?

Tags: rust

In my project, I want to enforce a coding convention that function types must be explicitly specified to ensure the code written by one developer can be readable by others.

Does anyone know if there is a way to make the Rust compiler throw a warning on the functions whose types are not explicitly specified?

For example, how to make `rustc` (or any equivalent tool) raise a warning at the below function `foo`, whose returned type isn't explicitly specified, but not `bar`.

```rust
// foo's return type is not explicitly specified
fn foo(...)  {
  ... 
  // return a string s
  return s 
}

// bar's return type is explicitly specified
fn bar(...) -> &str {
  ... 
  // return a string s
  return s 
}
```

Thank you for spending time looking at my question!

Comment: `foo()` doesn't return anything, similar to `void` in other languages. Rust also already forces explicit declaration of return types.

Comment: Not sure why this can be a problem. The return type which is not explicitly specified is always implicitly `()`, and compiler will throw an error if that's not correct. What kind of problems are you trying to prevent with this convention?

Comment: Your first example isn't even valid -- the compiler *already* throws an error there because you can't return `s` unless `s` is `()`. For example, if you try to return a string you'll get `expected '()', found struct 'String'`. The code is already readable. What you are trying to do doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Herohtar: this is just an illustration code. I encountered a situation while reading other people's code that returns complicated type (after type inference). So I wonder if it is a good practice to specify the returned type explicitly.

Comment: @Cerberus, MeetTitan: Oh I see. Thanks for pointing that out. I was confused between OCaml and Rust at that point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No

And you shouldn't do that, even if you could. In rust, the function

```rust
fn foo() {
    // ...
}
```

is unambiguously equivalent to the function

```rust
fn foo() -> () {
    // ...
}
```

so there is no reason to require that all functions should have an explicit return type. In fact, clippy even has a [warn by default lint](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#unused_unit)
for explicitly returning the unit type.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that Clippy's feature! I was confused by the type inference of Rust and OCaml at that point